# Samurai Favored Class options

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Do [Samurai](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/samurai/) have any favored class options? None are listed on D20PFSRD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Samurai uses the Cavalier Favored Class Bonuses

The [samurai](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classes/samurai.html) is an alternate class for Cavaliers, like the [Antipaladin](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/coreClasses/paladin.html#antipaladin-(alternate-class)) and [Ninja](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classes/ninja.html#ninja).

You will notice that you will not see the favoured class bonus on the Antipaladin (paladin), ninja (rogue) or samurai (cavalier). All three are alternate classes from their base class (in parenthesis) and unlike archetypes, they replace many core abilities of the base class, and are labelled as *Alternate Classes* instead.

Here is the introduction text before the samurai and ninja class from *Ultimate Combat* (page 5):

> Alternate classes are similar to base classes, save that they “replace” a preexisting base class for a given character (for more information on different class types, see page 8). The samurai is an alternate version of the cavalier, a master of armored combat who operates with impeccable honor and discipline. Inspired by both history and mythology, a samurai is a fearless paragon of war and greatly respected by the people he protects, dedicating himself to the way of the sword, bow, and horse.

And later on page 8 it explains what *Alternate Classes* are:

> **Alternate Classes**
>
> These are standalone classes whose basic ideas are very close to established base classes, yet whose required alterations would be too expansive for an archetype. In this case, that’s the samurai and the ninja—specifically Asian-themed classes that have long and unique histories, as well as great cultural cachet, but which are similar in concept to the established cavalier and rogue, respectively. An alternate class operates exactly as a base class, save that a character who takes a level in an alternate class can never take a level in its associated class—a samurai cannot also be a cavalier, and vice versa. The antipaladin from Advanced Player’s Guide is also an alternate class.

In other words, if the cavalier FCB works for the samurai, you can use it. But a character cannot multiclass the base class with the alternate class (rogue/ninja or samurai/cavalier) because they are essentially the same class with several changes.

Example, elves's FCB for cavaliers is the following:

> Add +1 hit point to the cavalier’s mount.

If your samurai has a mount, that should be applied to that mount. Otherwise, that race simply has no FCB for samurai other than the standard 1 extra hit point or skill point.

Comment: I actually didn't know this. Well answered.